# How to permanently change the zoom of diagnostic tools UI in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

The diagnostic tools window UI is too big in my VS installation and I would like to premanently fix it and not have to ctrl+scroll each time.
[image: too big!]

I have already been to a similar question regarding the global font size of VS but I can't find the specific display item from environments>fonts to change font size of diagnostic tools in VS.
I have tried using the reset zoom extension to fix this but to no avail.
And I don't want to keep ctrl+scrolling each time the window is launched.
Is there any way for this?